# How to use cmake for Torch in VSCode

Tags: c++, cmake, pytorch

I tried to run the minimal example by the Pytorch C++ API from [here](https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/installing.html#minimal-example) which uses cmake.
To build my program at the end I do:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/absolute/path/to/libtorch ..
cmake --build . --config Release
```

which runs fine and then I can run the program that has been built (I use macOS).
Now, I tried to do the same thing in VSCode from [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cmake-linux).
In VSCode I get the error that:

```
[cmake]   CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package):
[cmake]   By not providing "FindTorch.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
[cmake]   asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Torch", but
[cmake]   CMake did not find one.
[cmake] 
[cmake]   Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Torch" with any of
[cmake]   the following names:
[cmake] 
[cmake]     TorchConfig.cmake
[cmake]     torch-config.cmake
[cmake] 
[cmake]   Add the installation prefix of "Torch" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
[cmake]   "Torch_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Torch"
[cmake]   provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
[cmake]   installed.
```

I tried to use these to commands in `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "/Users/myusername/external_library_include/libtorch")
include_directories("/Users/myusername/external_library_include/libtorch")
```

However, it did not help. I think I should somehow let the CMake in VSCode know the command below:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/absolute/path/to/libtorch ..
```

However, it seems I cannot find how to do it.

Comment: Are you using the cmake tools plugin? Just configure it in the settings https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/cmake-settings.md

Comment: I added an entry like the one below but still does not find torch:
"cmake.configureArgs" :["-D/Users/myusername/external_library_include/libtorch"]

Comment: Looks like you missed `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` from the setting? I'd recommend using the settings gui rather than editing the json to reduce the chance of typos in the setting names